# Why isn't this code working?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm making a very simple calculator on Android. It shows no error on eclipse, but when I run it on my Android device, it stops working on clicking the buttons.

Here's my XML:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.simplecalculator.MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_a_no"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
        />

        <requestFocus />
    

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plus"
        android:text="@string/minus"
        android:onClick="minusClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/multiply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_below="@+id/plus"
        android:text="@string/multiply" 
        android:onClick="multiplyClick"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/divide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/multiply"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/multiply"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/minus"
        android:text="@string/divide"
        android:onClick="divideClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/equals"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/divide"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/minus"
        android:onClick="equalClick"
        android:text="@string/equals" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/_1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/_1" 
        android:onClick="_1click"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/_2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/_1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/_1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/_1"
        android:text="@string/_2" 
        android:onClick="_2click"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/divide"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/divide"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/divide"
        android:onClick="clearClick"
        android:text="@string/ce" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/_1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="127dp"
        android:hint="@string/plus"
        android:onClick="plusClick"
        android:text="@string/plus" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/_4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/_1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/_2"
        android:text="@string/_4" 
        android:onClick="_4click"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/_5"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/_4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/_4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/_2"
        android:text="@string/_5"
        android:onClick="_5click" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/_6"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/_5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/_5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/_5"
        android:text="@string/_6" 
        android:onClick="_6click"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/_7"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/_4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/_5"
        android:text="@string/_7" 
        android:onClick="_7click"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/_8"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/_5"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/_6"
        android:text="@string/_8" 
        android:onClick="_8click"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/_9"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/_5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/_5"
        android:text="@string/_9" 
        android:onClick="_9click"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/_3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/_5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/_2"
        android:text="@string/_3" 
        android:onClick="_3click"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/_0"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/_6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/_6"
        android:text="@string/_0" 
        android:onClick="_0click"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my Java code:

```js
package com.example.simplecalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  private double vrble;
  private double rslt;
  private double vrble2;
  String text;
  EditText etext;
  Button plus;
  Button minus;
  Button multiply;
  Button divide;
  Button equal;

  @
  Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
      vrble = 0;
      rslt = 0;
      etext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
      minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
      multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
      divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);
      equal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equals);
    } else {
      vrble = 0;
      rslt = 0;
      vrble2 = 0;
      etext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
      minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
      multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiply);
      divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);
      equal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.equals);



    }

  }

  public void _0click(View v) {
    text = etext.getText().toString();
    etext.setText(text + "0");
  }
  public void _1click(View v) {
    text = etext.getText().toString();
    etext.setText(text + "1");
  }
  public void _2click(View v) {
    text = etext.getText().toString();
    etext.setText(text + "2");
  }
  public void _3click(View v) {
    text = etext.getText().toString();
    etext.setText(text + "3");
  }
  public void _4click(View v) {
    text = etext.getText().toString();
    etext.setText(text + "4");
  }
  public void _5click(View v) {
    text = etext.getText().toString();
    etext.setText(text + "5");
  }
  public void _6click(View v) {
    text = etext.getText().toString();
    etext.setText(text + "6");
  }
  public void _7click(View v) {
    text = etext.getText().toString();
    etext.setText(text + "7");
  }
  public void _8click(View v) {
    text = etext.getText().toString();
    etext.setText(text + "8");
  }
  public void _9click(View v) {
    text = etext.getText().toString();
    etext.setText(text + "9");
  }

  public void plusClick(View v) {
    vrble = Double.parseDouble(etext.getText().toString());
    etext.setText("");
    vrble2 = Double.parseDouble(etext.getText().toString());
    rslt = vrble + vrble2;
  }
  public void minusClick(View v) {
    vrble = Double.parseDouble(etext.getText().toString());
    etext.setText("");
    vrble2 = Double.parseDouble(etext.getText().toString());
    rslt = vrble - vrble2;
  }
  public void multiplyClick(View v) {
    vrble = Double.parseDouble(etext.getText().toString());
    etext.setText("");
    vrble2 = Double.parseDouble(etext.getText().toString());
    rslt = vrble * vrble2;
  }
  public void divideClick(View v) {
    vrble = Double.parseDouble(etext.getText().toString());
    etext.setText("");
    vrble2 = Double.parseDouble(etext.getText().toString());
    rslt = vrble / vrble2;
  }
  public void clearClick(View v) {
    vrble = 0;
    rslt = 0;
    etext.setText("0");
  }
  public void equalClick(View v) {
    etext.setText("" + rslt);
  }@
  Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @
  Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

What should I do?!!?!

Comment: Look at the logcat to get a detailed error. It should be clear enough for you to know what is causing the issue.

Comment: It would be helpful to post your LogCat errors.

Comment: @blackbelt what's he's doing with the + is correct. He's getting the current text of the edittext, and then concatenating the number that has been pressed onto the end of the string in the edittext. He's not doing it as a calculation

Comment: Eclipse is showing no error in the code.... when i press the buttons for an operation the application shuts down....

Answer (score 0):

One issue that I can se is a `NumberFormatException` that you might get. See these lines in any of your method like `plusClick()`:

```
vrble = Double.parseDouble(etext.getText().toString());
etext.setText(""); //setting EditText to empty
vrble2 = Double.parseDouble(etext.getText().toString()); // parsing the empty string to Double
```

You are setting the `eText` to `""` and then you are parsing it to `Double` in the next line. This is throwing the error. You might need to clear your login for all the actions like plus minus etc.

For more, your stacktrace will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @Shobhit Puri, but can you help me out by suggesting an alternative to move forth.... :)